# Query with groovy.sql.sql didn't work but it work with MySQLWorkbench

Tags: grails, groovy

I am using Grails, work with MySQL by using groovy.sql.sql.

I did query in my controller but it didn't work. While I copied my sql code to run in mySQL Workbench, it worked normally.

Here is my code in controller,

```
def createSomething(){
  def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
  def Title = params.playlistName
  def StartDate = params.startDate
  def EndDate = params.endDate

  def map = [title:Title, start:StartDate, end:EndDate]
  sql.execute (
    "START TRANSACTION;"+
    "BEGIN;"+
    "INSERT INTO playlist (`name`) VALUES ('$map.title');"+
    "SELECT playlist.id from playlist where playlist.name =  '$map.title' INTO @playlistId;"+
    "INSERT INTO playlist_has_media(`idMedia`,`order`,`idPlaylist`)VALUES(1,1,@playlistId),(2,2,@playlistId),(3,3,@playlistId);"+
    "INSERT INTO schedule(`name`,`startDate`,`endDate`,`idPlaylist`,`isSync`)VALUES('$map.title', '$map.start', '$map.end', @playlistId, 1);"+
    "COMMIT;"
  )

}
```

It showed me an error but I copied from printed sql code to mySQL Workbench to run. It worked.

Comment: Can you please post the error?

Comment: are you passing down user provided strings in sql queries?  this has great potential for SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the single quotes:

```
 def createSomething(){
        def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
        def Title = params.playlistName
        def StartDate = params.startDate
        def EndDate = params.endDate

        def map = [title:Title, start:StartDate, end:EndDate]

        sql.execute (
                "START TRANSACTION;"+
                        "BEGIN;"+
                        "INSERT INTO playlist (`name`) VALUES ($map.title);"+
                        "SELECT playlist.id from playlist where playlist.name =  $map.title INTO @playlistId;"+
                        "INSERT INTO playlist_has_media(`idMedia`,`order`,`idPlaylist`)VALUES(1,1,@playlistId),(2,2,@playlistId),(3,3,@playlistId);"+
                        "INSERT INTO schedule(`name`,`startDate`,`endDate`,`idPlaylist`,`isSync`)VALUES($map.title, $map.start, $map.end, @playlistId, 1);"+
                        "COMMIT;"
        )

    }
```

Also maybe you could make it more groovy

```
sql.withTransaction {stmt ->
    def playlistId = sql.executeInsert("INSERT INTO playlist (`name`) VALUES ($map.title);")
    sql.executeInsert("INSERT INTO playlist_has_media(`idMedia`,`order`,`idPlaylist`)VALUES(1,1,$playlistId),(2,2,$playlistId),(3,3,$playlistId);")
    sql.executeInsert("INSERT INTO schedule(`name`,`startDate`,`endDate`,`idPlaylist`,`isSync`)VALUES($map.title, $map.start, $map.end, $playlistId, 1);")
}
```